# Send date from C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have issue with converting `datetime` in C# to `date` in SQL Server.

I constantly get this error message:

> input string was not in correct format.

I tried this query

```
insert into TasksCopy (Start_Date) 
values (CONVERT(date, '10/01/2017'));
```

It worked in SQL Server Management Studio, but didn't work using C# program in Visual Studio.

However the query below worked in both Visual Studio and Management Studio:

```
insert into TasksCopy (Time) 
values (CONVERT(time, '17:00:00'));
```

I tried this way using my C# app to send `datetime` variable called `datetime`:

```
insert into TasksCopy (Start_Date) 
values (CONVERT(date, datetime.date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")));
```

however that still did not work.

The code below did not work either:

```
string query = $"insert into TasksCopy (Start_Date) values (CONVERT(date, @date));";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTime.Date);
```

That also did not work.

What is the correct way to send data to SQL Server as `date` data type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to add the insert date, you can call SQL GetDate() for instance..

Comment: Why do you need to `CONVERT`? It will work without that.

Comment: You are missing the point.  Pass the values in as parameters.  The parameters will take care of the types.

Comment: i can send time without using CONVERT but still it is not working for sending date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date managing is always a pain no matter what language, but somehting that seems to always work in SQL engines is to send the date string as

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

So you can try something like this:

```
insert into TasksCopy (Start_Date) values (CONVERT(date, datetime.date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")));
```

Comment: It will work by just passing the date in the parameter. You do not need to `ToString()` it into a specific format.

Comment: heh, the accepted answer gets a -1, but meanwhile it helps the OP, doesn't matter :)

Comment: Getting the right answer that matters after all.

Comment: Glad it help you man, I wish you success in taming the C#+MSSQL beast